# Stopping CoreLocation background updates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-location, cllocationmanager

My app registers for background location updates (not Significant Change. I need more granularity than kilometers)

That part works fine. I just want to **stop** the updates after the app has been in the background for 60 minutes. The way I'm doing it right now is to call `stopUpdatingLocation` in my CLLocationManager delegate.

However, I am *unsure* if this will actually stop my app from receiving background location updates, or if it *will*, but will just ignore them. Ideally, I'd like to not have my app be responsible for battery drain except for a small period of time after user activity.

Apple's documentation tends to send me in circles on this one. Right when I think "Executing Code in the Background" is about to spill the answer, it directs me to "Location Awareness Programming Guide." Right when that one is about to get specific about this question, it sends me back to "Executing Code in the Background." :)

Comment: Note: I'm not interested in Significant Change Location Updates. I have extensively tested this in urban and suburban areas, and I sometimes get 0 updates even after 3km of travel. I want high quality location data, but for the limited period of during app usage to up to an hour afterwards. I just want confirmation of whether ```stopUpdatingLocation``` will actually stop the GPS / wifi radio triangulation / trilateration. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether your app has *total* control over this, but the docs for `stopUpdatingLocation` do state the following ...

> Disabling event delivery gives the receiver the option of disabling the appropriate hardware (and thereby saving power) when no clients need location data

Which would suggest that should your app be the only one requesting background location data, and you request it to stop the GPS receiver would disable the appropriate hardware to save on power, which I think it was you're looking for.

What I can suggest is that you enable **Power logging** in **Settings -> Developer**, then run your app for an hour or so to a point where you think GPS is disabled, run for another hour and then compare the power usage in Instruments. This should provide you with a much clearer picture.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I'll give that a shot. It will take a while to definitively know if my app is behaving well, but it's worth the time investment. I just wish there was a clear answer in the Apple docs about something so important. They really try to get people into Significant Change (understandably so, battery-wise) but there are so many apps that want to know what's going on a block or two away from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `stopUpdatingLocation` will indeed stop GPS and so on, but if you place this call inside `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` of your `CLLocationManager delegate`, then it might never be called.

Keep in mind that this method is only executed whenever a *more accurate position* or a (according to the active distance filter) *significantly different position* is available. If the device does not move at all and if the circumstances affecting the accuracy also do not change, it may not be called for hours (I have verified it for several minutes myself) and GPS will also stay enabled for this long.

For apps that only work in the foreground, you can use an `NSTimer` of 60minutes, but for apps that run in the background, the closest to a working solution that I have found so far, is a scheduled `UILocalNotification`. But even that requires the user to confirm an alert, before the app is restarted and able to turn the GPS off.

Maybe `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` is the key to a better solution, but I have not completely figured it out, yet.