# CLLocationManger stopUpdatingLocation behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am working on `CLLocationManager`. My App is register for Background "App registers for location updates". But When I am calling  "`stopUpdatingLocation`" and went to background my app is not running more (My app become in Inactive state).

Why `LocationManager` behaves like that? Even my app is register for background location updates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689296/stopping-corelocation-background-updates

Comment: Check comment of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561355/location-service-going-to-inactive-state-in-iphone-5/19561540#19561540

Comment: @VishwaPatel I already set          self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

Answer (score 1):

You have to  Read  and [Check this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).

You have to Some changes in app.plist file like:

1) If your app use on location services to function properly, You have to add **location-services** to **UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities**.

2)if your app requires GPS service, you have to add GPS to **UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities**.

3) if you need to run your app longer then 10 minutes in the background, add location to **UIBackgroundModes**. Then your location manager will deliver locations beyond the **10-minute-limit**.

4)you should also set **NSLocationUsageDescription** (can also be localized)

Comment: My app is register for Background location update. I want my location at some point not all time. So I am calling "stopUpdatingLocation" when I don't want location updates. But Once I called "stopUpdatingLocation" after some time etc 20 sec my app stop executing single line of code also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used `locationManager:didFailWithError:` method? The possible reasons were enumerated.